# Aligning multiline formula: Break within fences and AMS style

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align, best-practices

I have a rather long formula and I would like to align it in accordance with [AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) (see below screenshot from page 119).
[image: screenshot]

I am not able to reproduce this behavior. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{{E}(N(\theta_{q}))}{\mathcal{E}(N)} =\frac{1}{f(L)} \Big[ &2\arctan(\cot(q/2)) -2 \arctan(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) & &\\
&{}+\left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) \frac{ 3 + \left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) ^{2}}{1 + \left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) ^{2}} & &\\
& & {} +\left(\cos(q) -2\right)\cot(q/2) &\Big].
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It typesets as

[image]

What would be the best way to comply with this rule in my case?

Comment: You want to use `multline`

Comment: Honestly, whenever I edit manuscripts, this is one of the AMS recommendations I tend to ignore. I tend to align a construction like this by the `[` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities. In the first, a bit of visual formatting is needed to push the second line a bit to the right.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\frac{E(N(\theta_{q}))}{\mathcal{E}(N)} =
  \frac{1}{f(L)} \Bigl[ 2\arctan(\cot(q/2)) -2 \arctan(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) \\
\qquad % visually determined
+(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) \frac{3 + (\cot(q/2)+f(L)) ^{2}}{1 + (\cot(q/2)+f(L))^{2}} \\
+(\cos(q) -2)\cot(q/2) \Bigr].
\end{multline*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{E(N(\theta_{q}))}{\mathcal{E}(N)} =
  \begin{multlined}[t]
  \frac{1}{f(L)} \Bigl[ 2\arctan(\cot(q/2)) -2 \arctan(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) \\
+(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) \frac{3 + (\cot(q/2)+f(L)) ^{2}}{1 + (\cot(q/2)+f(L))^{2}} \\
+(\cos(q) -2)\cot(q/2) \Bigr].
\end{multlined}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout, based on the  multlined environment (from`mathtools`) and the `linegoal` package, which measures the relaining soace on the line:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[verbose]{linegoal}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{{E}(N(\theta_{q}))}{\mathcal{E}(N)} = \frac{1}{f(L)}\begin{multlined}[t][\linegoal]\Bigl[ 2\arctan(\cot(q/2)) -2 \arctan(\cot(q/2)+f(L)) \\
{}+\left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) \frac{ 3 + \left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) ^{2}}{1 + \left( \cot(q/2)+f(L)\right) ^{2}}\\
 {} +\left(\cos(q) -2\right)\cot(q/2).\Bigr]
\end{multlined} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]